# Why would sql plus not save a new row even after using commit?

Tags: sql, oracle, insert, save, commit

I'm learning DML for my class and trying to insert new rows and using oracle 18c. Even after I use the commit command the row isn't saved. After I close the sql plus window and open it again and type

```
SELECT*FROM acctmanager;
```

it still says `No rows selected.` What could be the problem?

[enter image description here][image: 1]

Comment: Can you access the row after commit before closing sql plus?

Comment: Please post a complete example with insert and select one after another. Your current question is not clear at all and this situation is not reproducible (and I cannot imagine it ever possible)

Comment: I am able to access the row after commit and before closing.

Comment: What if you try to connect again, in the same SQLPlus windows; Something like  `select * ...`,  then `connect user/password@DB` and then again `select * ...` ?

Comment: I also tried that. Could it be because I'm logged in as system for the username?

Comment: Please prefix your object like 'insert into <owner>.acctmanager , select * from <owner>.acctmanager. You probably have the object 'acctmanager' scattered around among multiple schemas/users.

Answer (score 0):

My bet is ACCTMANAGER is a global temporary table. These are permanent data structures, but any data persists only for the duration of a transaction or a session, depending on how the table was created. [Find out more](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/temporary-tables).

> I am able to access the row after commit and before closing.

This strong suggests the table was created with ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS clause.

Easy enough to check:

```
select table_name, temporary
from user_tables
where table_name = 'ACCTMANAGER'
```

Comment: That sounds like that could be it, but is that something that oracle can do automatically because I didn't set it to do that. This is the script I am going off of:                          
 CREATE TABLE acctmanager
(amid CHAR(4),
 amfirst VARCHAR2(12)  NOT NULL,
 amlast VARCHAR2(12)  NOT NULL,
 amedate DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE,
 amsal NUMBER(8,2),
 amcomm NUMBER(7,2) DEFAULT 0,
 region CHAR(2),
  CONSTRAINT acctmanager_amid_pk PRIMARY KEY (amid),
  CONSTRAINT acctmanager_region_ck
     CHECK (region IN ('N', 'NW', 'NE', 'S', 'SE', 'SW', 'W', 'E')));

Comment: No, Oracle does not automatically turn a normal table into a GTT. So, what we have here is a puzzle. You assert that the database is doing something weird. But we can only counter-assert that your database is **not** doing something weird. Oracle has not been the leading enterprise RDBMS for several decades by losing committed transactions. It is much more likely that you misunderstand what's happening; there's some quirk in the environment or configuration that you have overlooked. Unfortunately there's not much we can do to help you further.

Comment: That is extremely likely because I am very new to this. I appreciate the help. I'll keep learning as I go along also. Thank You!